# Running Coded UI tests from MTM without a build?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have created a few coded ui tests and linked them to the test case, and they now appear as automated and you can see the dll they link to in the test case details.

Now that I want to run the tests, MTM refuses to even start the test unless a build is defined.

However: I want to run the tests against a statically installed application in the lab environment. This is an application that I manually install, and I get this application already compiled, so no need to play around building it.

So how can I take the build server out of the loop? I don't need the application built or deployed, I'm already doing that.

All I want is the tests to run on the lab environment specified against an application that is already preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

It's asking you to define the build of the test solution, assuming that it's different from your application under test.  The test assembly will be deployed to the test environment after you specify it in MTM.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553270(v=vs.110).aspx) may help you with the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

It is asking you to create a build for your Coded UI test solution. It requires that the tests be built so that it has something to execute when you run the tests. Assuming that your tests were recorded using your statically deployed application then they will test that same application.